# Installing mod_wsgi with python 2.7 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, mod-wsgi

I tried to install mod_wsgi on my ubuntu server using the package manager, but noticed it depends on python 2.6. I'm using python 2.7, and would rather avoid installing 2.6...

Does mod_wsgi really depend on python 2.6, even if I intend to run only python 2.7 with it? If not, is there a way to install mod_wsgi having only python 2.7 installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've confirmed that the mod_wsgi package (libapache-mod-wsgi) supports both python 2.6 and 2.7. Checking `/usr/lib/apache2/modules` revealed the existence of both `mod_wsgi.so-2.6` and `mod_wsgi.so-2.7`.

To install the package without having to install python 2.6 I've used `apt-get download libapache2-mod-wsgi` to download the package without installing, and then `dpkg --force-all -i libapache2-mod-wsgi` to install it by itself (i.e., without python 2.6). It automatically symlinked to the `mod_wsgi.so-2.7` module.

PS: This is apparently a [well known bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655466).

Comment: I believe you mean libapache2-mod-wsgi (forgot the 2)

Comment: You're right, updated.